# Convert to valid decimal data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a column `[Cash] nvarchar(50)` that has data that will later be converted to `decimal(9,3)` during an import process,some of the data is consistent with normal looking numeric values such as **134.630,-80.662** and **324.372.** Occasionally I have data with multiple dots for the numeric values such as `1.324.372  and -2.134.630.` Is there a way of removing this extra dot.

Comment: Does `'-2.134.630.'` have a dot at the end as well or is that a full stop?

Comment: So, digit grouping symbol is `.`. What is the decimal separator ?

Comment: Can you specify the behaviour more exactly?  Do all values have 3 decimal places, for example.  As written, it's not actually clear what the numbers *should* be...

Comment: 1.324.372 and -2.134.630. which dotted need to be removed any pattern ?

Comment: @Martin Smith that is a full stop

Comment: @Bogdan Sahlean the behaviour of the data is constant with 3 decimal places but t-clausen.dk answer covers both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @yourtable table(cash varchar(20))
insert @yourtable values('1.324.372')
insert @yourtable values('-2.134.630')
insert @yourtable values('1.234.567.89')
```

Old Code:

```
select reverse(replace(replace(stuff(reverse(cash), charindex(
    '.', reverse(cash)), 1, ','), '.', ''), ',', '.')) 
from @yourtable
```

Slightly upgraded code(result is the same):

```
select reverse(stuff(reverse(replace(cash, '.', '')), 
    charindex('.', reverse(cash)), 1, '.'))
from @yourtable
```

Result:

```
1324.372
-2134.630
1234567.89
```

Answer (score 1):

You could;

```
select case when len(cash) - len(replace(cash, '.', '')) > 1 then
    reverse(stuff(reverse(cash), charindex('.', reverse(cash)), 1, ''))
else    
    cash
end
from T
```

Comment: This what I was trying initially

Answer (score 0):

Create a view that includes a calculated field with the proper value.

That way you can still see the varchar value and the corresponding decimal value.

Something like this:

select
 [Cash],
 cast(replace([Cash],'.','') as decimal) as [CashDecimal]
from ....